# DocumentDB: How to run a query without timing out

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, timeout, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to the documentDb. I wrote a stored procedure that checks all records and update them under certain circumstances.

**Current scenario:**

It would run 100 records at a time, updates them and after running few times( taking 100 records at a time and updating) it is timing out.

**Expectation**

Run the script on all the records without timing out.

The document has close to a million records. So, running the same script multiple times manually is not a the way I am looking for.

Can anyone please advise me how I can achieve that?

Comment: Did you mean "collection has close to a million documents" when you wrote, "document has close to a million records"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr; Keep calling the sproc with the query continuation token being passed back and forth.

A few thoughts:

1. There is no capacity of RUs for collections that will allow you to do all million in one call to the sproc.
2. Sprocs run in isolation on a single replica. This means that they can be transactional but their use will have lower throughput than a regular query that can use all replicas to satisfy the request, so unless you need it to be in a sproc, I recommend using direct queries for reads that don't need to be transactional with writes. Even then, with a million documents, your queries will max out and you'll have to run the query again with a continuation token.
3. If you must use a sproc... As you are probably aware since you have done the 100 at a time thing, each query returns a continuation token. You can actually add that to the package that you send back from your sproc when it times out. Then you can pass that back into another call to the same sproc and write your sproc to pick up where you left off. The [documentdb-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils) library for node.js automatically re-calls the sproc until done as long as you follow [this pattern for writing your sprocs](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#pattern-for-writing-stored-procedures). If you are using node.js, you could use that (but it has not yet been upgraded to support partitioned collections) or you could write the equivalent in whatever platform you are using.

Comment: Hi Larry.

I think I did not explain it correctly, i did not select 100 records at a time but when i tried picking all records it just picked up 100 at a time. WIll there be no time limitation for direct update queries ?

Comment: The default `responseOptions.pageSize` is 100. You have to set it to -1 if you want it to try to get as many as possible, but I recommend against that in a sproc (but it's fine in a direct query). I usually set it at 1000 or 10,000. This allows the sproc to make incremental progress and memoize it when the sproc exceeded the execution time limit. The approach I'm recommending counts on it failing for very large result sets. Here is an example sproc that sets the pageSize and is restartable if it times out: https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/countDocuments.coffee